# How to use childNodes for XML document?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, nodes, element

i created the following javascript:

```
<script>
    function stats(cod) {
        var th = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
        var tds = document.getElementsByClassName("pt");

        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
                var xmlDoc = httpRequest.responseXML.documentElement;

                th[0].innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                tds[0].innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('what')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                tds[1].innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('office')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                tds[2].innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('www')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                tds[3].innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('over')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            }
        }
        httpRequest.open("GET","getData.php?codice=" + cod, true);
        httpRequest.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

I'm sure it is a better way to read the XML content and assign its values to the table TDs. I tried to get an array of all elements contained within `xmlDoc` using `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('response').childNodes;` but the result seems to be undefined.

EDIT:

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<response>
    <name>The name</name>
    <what>What is</what>
    <office>The office</office>
    <www>The website</www>
    <over>Yes</over>
</response>
```

Comment: Show us a sample of the XML and then explain in words which data you want to read out. Doing `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('response').childNodes` does not make sense as `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` and that does not have any `childNodes` property, only each item in the `NodeList` has a `childNodes` property.

Comment: I have updated my question. What does `childNodes` property refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access the `response` element as

```
var response = httpRequest.responseXML.documentElement;
```

I would then not try to use `childNodes` as that can include text node between elements while using `response.children` would give you the child elements, but only in modern browsers. In that case elements also have a `textContent` property you could use in case of all those `firstChild.nodeValue` accesses:

```
var childElements = response.children;

th[0].innerHTML = childElements[0].textContent;
tds[0].innerHTML = childElements[1].textContent;
...
```

On the other hand once the order of elements in your XML changes or an element is omitted you will read out the wrong data so there is some advantage in using e.g. `response.getElementsByTagName('www')[0].textContent` to go by the name.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like collection of elements.

A specific element (including each member of a collection) may have `childNodes`. The collection itself won't.